# How to write the iterative version of recursive scheme code

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (g-sum f a b)
  (if (= a b)
      (f b)
      (+ (f b) (g-sum f a (- b 1)))))
```

I'm not sure how to change this so it can iterative.

Comment: What, if anything, have you done to attempt this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(define (g-sum f a b)
  (let loop ((acc 0) (b b))
    (if (< b a)
        acc
        (loop (+ (f b) acc) (- b 1)))))
```

The trick for transforming a recursive process into an iterative process is to pass around a parameter that accumulates the result and return it at the end of the recursion, making sure that the recursive call is the last thing we do in the recursive step, with no computations pending.

I'm using a named `let` for simplicity, but this is not required, as using a helper inner procedure would have the same effect. The above code is equivalent to this:

```
(define (g-sum f a b)
  (define (loop acc b)
    (if (< b a)
        acc
        (loop (+ (f b) acc) (- b 1))))
  (loop 0 b))
```

If you still have trouble grasping the above code, remember that an inner helper procedure can be extracted as a separate procedure as long as we pass along the required parameters. The point is, you *need* an extra parameter to be used as an accumulator, how exactly you do this is irrelevant, personally I prefer to use a named `let`. This is equivalent to my previous two solutions:

```
(define (g-sum f a b)
  (loop f a b 0))

(define (loop f a b acc)
  (if (< b a)
      acc
      (loop f a (- b 1) (+ (f b) acc))))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what " let loop" and "acc" means

Comment: @siri acc is just a parameter. A named `let` is simply a shortcut for defining a helper procedure which happens to be called `loop`. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

See exercise 1.30 in SICP. [Bill has a solution here](http://www.billthelizard.blogspot.com/2010/04/sicp-exercise-130-iterative-sums.html).